# Data-informed grouping of covariates in Bayesian Hierarchical Modeling?

Tags: r, bayesian, prior, hierarchical-bayesian, jags

Is there a way to place a prior on the first stage's betas that allows the second stage groups to be determined from the data? I am working with co-exposures where I am not super confident in how they should be grouped. I have been recommended the below paper but it is way above my head.

[MacLehose 2007 - Bayesian Methods for Highly Correlated Exposure Data](https://journals.lww.com/epidem/Fulltext/2007/03000/Bayesian_Methods_for_Highly_Correlated_Exposure.6.aspx)

Comment: Sorry if I'm unclear. My brain does not statistic well at this level.

Comment: Can you describe your data and model, and your goal? This is very little i fo for us to work on. Also, please include relevant info from the link, few people will read a complete paper for you!